# How is the parcel body of a Teradata CLI response decoded?

Tags: teradata

The Teradata sample CLI code located at /opt/teradata/client/15.00/sample/clisamp.c runs a SELECT statement on Teradata database and outputs the parcel body results into a file.

How can the contents of the parcel body be decoded? What is it's structure? And does it contain datatype information?

If it does not have datatype information, can the code be easily modified to provide datatypes of the resultset?

I believe the resulting output file from running the teradata sample code contains the resultset of the SQL SELECT. But I'd like to be able to interpret/decode the results.

Comment: Did you check the manuals? http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/Interface_Tools/B035_2418_035K/2418Ch09.50.070.html

Comment: Yes I have. I didn't find this section in my searching of the document. Thanks. One thing that I have not figured out though is how to tell what the data type is. That text says the data type is in the item but doesn't explicitly say where it is, and what is its size. Same thing with the rest of the content. The text says length and format is there but does not explain exactly how it is laid out.